# Remove Shell Extension Folder X64

Tags: windows-registry, shell-extensions

I have a very strange shell extension folder which I just can't get rid of.

[image: "X64"-ShellExtension folder]

How can I get rid of this? I already downloaded **ShellExViewer**, but I cannot find any extension called "X64", nor are the other extensions which reside in that folder anywhere in the Viewer. I am also not able to find that folder in the registry, but that's probably because I don't know where to look.

How can I edit this so the contents of the folder are put in the "default" menu and not in a subfolder?

Comment: I would just reinstall windows.

Comment: Well, if the machine weren't my workplace computer, I'd actually do that, yes...

Comment: Where/when are you seeing the context-menu? That is, what are you right-clicking to get it? Does it happen when you right-click a drive? directory? the desktop? different types of files?

Comment: I was going to suggest that it is [from Total Commander](https://www.google.com/search?q=x64+submenu+context&safe=off), but that [may not be the case](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331753/topic/4437723). What is likely happening is that you have a few programs which provide both 32-bit and 64-bit shell-extensions and both are being installed. You should be able to remove one of them so that only a single copy appears.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka, so what happened? You clicked accept but did not state whether you solved it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that entry show up for all objects (drives, folders, files of any type) or just for particular file types? If it shows for all objects, check the registry below `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*`, particularly the `shell` and `shellex` subkeys. Try deleting the `*` subkey:

- Start regedit (as administrator) and navgate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*`.
- Click `File > Export...` and save the key to a file.
- Delete the key.

Does the `X64` entry still appear after that? Re-import the registry file you saved before to undo the change.

You could also try a registry search for `X64` (whole string in keys and data):

[image]

I don't think it's very likely that you'll find it that way, but it won't hurt to try. You need to look only below `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. You can stop the search when it hits `HKEY_CURRRENT_USER` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

As for [`ShellExView`](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html): an extension won't necessarily be registered with the same name that is displayed in the context menu. Start the program (as administrator) and order the extensions by company (it's unlikely to be a Microsoft extension, so you probably should focus on the non-Microsoft ones). Which non-MS extensions are listed there? Ignore the ones that you can clearly identify and disable the others.

Does that remove the context menu entry? If so: re-enable *half* of the disabled extensions. If the entry re-appears it's among that half, so disable half of those extensions again. Otherwise it's among the other half that's still disabled, so enable half of *those* extensions. Continue until you have narrowed down the problematic extension.

Comment: *> Delete the key [`HKCR\*`].*   Why not just rename it instead?

Comment: Renaming may have some side effects that removing won't (whatever the key is renamed to will be a valid type). In this case it probably won't make a difference, though.

Comment: The only side-effect would be if you don’t have permissions (which *should not* be a problem unless a virus or poorly behaved program added a subkey with special permissions), then some or all of it wouldn’t get renamed, but then you also wouldn’t be able to delete it anyway.

Comment: That is not a side-effect of renaming (or deleting) the key, and also not what I was talking about. If you rename the key from `*` to `foo` it becomes the registration for a type "foo" that something in the system may or may not use.

Comment: Why would you rename it to `foo`? Whenever I want to perform the test you described (which I have done countless times), I usually just append or prepend a `#` or something to the name. For example `*` would become `#*`, `*-`, etc. It works just fine and is much simpler than having to export/import.

Comment: Are you trying to be difficult or something? Obviously `foo` is just a placeholder. No matter *what* you rename the key to, that new name will be a registered type. And it's not like exporting and re-importing a key would require a Ph.D. in nuclear physics. *\*sheesh\**

Comment: It may not require a degree, but simply pressing `F2` is still much less work, and it’s also much safer. And *who cares* if it becomes a registered type‽ It’s **temporary**. Do you really think that a `.foo` or whatever file will suddenly/magically appear on the system and somehow get executed by itself? Besides, `*-`, `#*`, etc. are not valid types anyway, so you would *not* be creating a registered type (assuming it mattered in the first place). Like I said, I’ve renamed countless times without problem.

Comment: In any case, it’s not going to help anyway because if it were in there, it would have been listed in ShellExView and he already said it wasn’t.

Comment: You're free to provide an answer of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Ansgar Wiechers solution worked perfectly.

I had *Magiciso* option showing up on the right click context menu.

I checked and confirmed that *Magiciso* was uninstalled from my computer.
I opened `REGEDIT`, and deleted `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\MAGICISO`

But no difference.

I reboot my computer, but no change.

Then, I searched for any file that could be named *magic*, and found a .dll [windows shell extension module] name `C:\Program Files (x86)\MagicISO\misosh64.dll`

I tried to delete the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\MagicISO\`, but got an error that the contents in the directory is used by another application/opened somewhere else.

Then I tried the steps mentioned by Ansgar Wiechers, got the Magiciso option out from the right click context menu, but no success in removing the directory.

I restarted the computer, and after loggin in, the first thing I did was to delete the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\MagicISO\`, and success at last.

Thank you.